# Change tab content dynamically in material UI

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-design, url-routing, material-ui

I am having a div containing tabs (material ui) in my react application page. It has two tabs. One of the tab has listview (material-ui). I want to a behavior such that when I click any list item of the listview then my tab content should fade out (or hide or change) the listview and give another view to my tab. How could I achieve this.

```
return (
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <div className="videoPageTabs">
                    <Tabs>
                        <Tab label="Tags" style={{backgroundColor:"#293C8E"}}>
                            <TagList/>
                        </Tab>
```

ListItems component "TagList"

```
return (
            <div>
                <List id="parent-list-tags" >
                    <ListItem  primaryText="Item 1" onClick={this.handleClicked} />
                    <Divider/>
                    <ListItem primaryText="Item 2" onClick={this.handleClicked} />
                    <Divider/>
                    <ListItem primaryText="Item 3" onClick={this.handleClicked} />
                    <Divider/>
                    <ListItem primaryText="Item 4" onClick={this.handleClicked}/>
                    <Divider/>
                    <ListItem primaryText="Item 5" onClick={this.handleClicked}/>
                    <Divider/>
                    <ListItem primaryText="Item 6" onClick={this.handleClicked} />
                </List>

            </div>
```

"Tabs component".
You can see that I am passing Taglist as the view for tab "tags". I want this view to change whenever I click listitem. I want to replace "Taglist" 
component with another component "Component A" whenever any list item is clicked.

```
return (
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <div className="videoPageTabs">
                    <Tabs>
                        <Tab label="Tags" style={{backgroundColor:"#293C8E"}}>
                            <TagList/>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab label="Info" style={{backgroundColor:"#293C8E"}}>
                            <div>
                                <h3 style={styles.headline}>Title : Name</h3>


                            </div>
                        </Tab>
                    </Tabs>

                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>

        );
```

I want to replace that with another component everytime I click a list item. Is routers useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Tabs have a prop and value

```
value={this.state.value}
onChange={this.handleChange}
```

so you need to assign value to all your tabs:

```
 <Tab label="Tags" value="tags" >
```

and then your handlechange function would just switch to whichever tab you want.

Comment: I am able to switch between the tabs. But I want to change the content within the tab. As I said, I have list view in my tab. When I click to a list item,   I want that list view to disappear and another content to show up, in the same tab.

Comment: You will probably need react-router to handle that. Add a Link property to the list items, and make the contents of the tab {this.props.children}, and then just match the content to the routes. I've done something similar

Comment: I am putting my code in the edits. Please have a look and tell me when should I make the changes.

Comment: I have not been able to solve it. Can some please help me in this